# Static variable evaluates to null at json.put()

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I have a class only to store variables as keys like:

```
public class V {
    public static final String SHOW_OR_FOUND = "show_or_found";
    public static final int FAULT = -1;
}
```

I use them for keys and comparison, so it's more readable and avoids failures.

Now the problem. If I do something like the following in a method of another class:

```java
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put(V.SHOW_OR_FOUND, "something important to save")
```

it won't work. With debugger tool I can see V.SHOW_OR_FOUND evaluates to null. If I do something like:

```java
String test = V.SHOW_OR_FOUND;
json.put(test, "something important to save")
```

it works. Also, if I use V by calling its own class method, it works perfectly fine.

```java
this.save(V.SHOW_OR_FOUND, "something important to save")
```

I'm pulling my hairs over this because it makes absolutely no sense to me. Can please someone explain and give a solution to it?

I already tried things like:

```
String.valueOf(V.SHOW_OR_FOUND)
V.SHOW_OR_FOUND.toString()
```

The latter results in a NullPointerException, and yes I double and triple checked for spelling faults, even copy pasted the variable name.

Comment: This sounds like a development environment issue that cannot be solved by looking at out of context code snippets that are riddled with syntax errors.

Comment: As @Torben pointed out, that sounds like some IDE or Debug issue. Try the following things: (a) restart IDE. (b) rebuild module / project. (c) make sure that your code is indeed the code being debugged (I had situations where the debugged code didn't match the source because of changes in the meantime).